# 2 things one when is my fish in my breeding tank gonna give birth and 2 is my grey fish pregnant?

Tags: guppies

[image][image][image]
Is my grey fish pregnant also when will my fish in the breeding tank give birth ? Also if my grey fish is pregnant how long has she been ?

Comment: please read the other answers to pregnant guppy questions.